# Does Caprica reach some sort of conclusion?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, caprica

I watched the first half season of Caprica, but just couldn't bring myself to keep watching it based on its pacing and differences from BSG. I wanted some answers that Caprica claimed to be about answering, but never really got there.

So, did Caprica end up being wrapped up in some way, or was it totally cut off at the knees?

Comment: You got through half the season?  I couldn't even finish the pilot, it was so awful.

Comment: I wanted it to be good soooooo badly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series did reach a conclusion - there is definitely an ending to most of the storylines that are introduced throughout the series.

However, they do leave some plots open - partly in hope of being picked up for a second season - but many other series leave similar open endings (for example, The 4400).

In short, the series reaches a conclusion - but if you didn't enjoy it enough to get through a few episodes, then it probably isn't worth forcing your way through the rest.

Answer (score 4):

There was a whole **Next time on Caprica** at the end of the series in which:

> The sister was now a leader of sorts.
>  And Lacey was now the head nun

Comment: So... cut off at the knees I gather?

Comment: @Pyrodante they just basically went forward in time and added information that could be useful.

Comment: It was basically a preview of some of the plotlines that Season 2 would have had.  Nice to have, but wasn't a full wrapup.

Comment: @Keen basically.

Comment: @TheDoctor I need to not comment before getting my morning coffee.  That, or I need a thesaurus to look up synonyms for 'basically'...

Comment: @Keen [primarily](http://thesaurus.com/browse/basically) ^_^